# How to make a link to the next record in my plugin?

Tags: octobercms

I have a plugin including record list and record details. On record details page I want to have a link like this:

```
<a href="#" class="neighbour__link text--title-big">next</a>
```

So it's the link to the next record without url. How can I get this url with october? Is there a way to get and filter all records or may be any ready function to get a next record url?

Comment: Check out [OctoberCMS's Pagination Service](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/pagination). There are many ways to do this. I suggest to experiment with [components](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components). If you are still stuck edit your question with what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution working for me.

In the model:

```
public function nextRecord($currentID) {
    $nextRecord = Project::where('id', '<>', $currentID)->where('id','>', $currentID)-> orderBy('id', 'ASC')->first();
    if ($nextRecord == null) {
        $nextRecord = Project::where('id', '<>', $currentID)->where('id','<', $currentID)-> orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
    }
    return $nextRecord;
}
```

In the template:

```
<section class="neighbour clearfix">
    {% set next_record = record.nextRecord(record.id) %}
    <a href="/projects/{{ next_record.slug }}" class="neighbour__link text--title-big">{{ next_record.name }}</a>
</section>
```

A flow of this solution is that the records are sorted by id, not by adding time. So if I want to sort them by time, I probably need to add some timestamp.